# How do I mark (or) shade the area below the graph of Surface plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a 3D surface graph for the following equation 
 t_t <= (xi_i - xi_j) . sqrt(rho). I have included my code. But I would like to mark or shade the area under the graph of this surface plot. How do I solve it?

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);

Z = X.* sqrt(Y);

figure;

colormap(jet)

surf(X,Y,Z) 

colorbar

xlabel('Distance between two spatial points \xi_i & \xi_j (\xi_i - \xi_j)');

ylabel('Density(\rho)');

zlabel('Transmission Delay (t_t)');
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show an example image of what you would like? somethinc like `surfc`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Hi. Thanks for the reply. But I am not looking for surfc command. I am looking for something like this  https://imgur.com/O1gDzDv  . But I edited using 3D paint.  Is there any matlab command which will mark the area under this curve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the extra surfaces by building up a new set of matrices to pass to [`surf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html), with a few different options based on how you want the results to look...

### Option #1: Fill the sides, one surface object:

If you want to just fill in the sides, you can add a new row and column on each side of your matrices like so:

```
[R, C] = size(Z);
Xfill = [nan X(1, :) nan; X(:, [1 1:C C]); nan X(R, :) nan];
Yfill = [nan Y(1, :) nan; Y(:, [1 1:C C]); nan Y(R, :) nan];
Zfill = [nan zeros(1, C) nan; zeros(R, 1) Z zeros(R, 1); nan zeros(1, C) nan];

surf(Xfill, Yfill, Zfill);
view(-120, 30);
```

This allows you to plot the surface and sides with a single call to `surf`, with this result:

[image]

### Option #2: Fill the sides and bottom, one surface object:

If you would also like to fill in the bottom of the shape, you can wrap the surface around and under itself by adding new columns and then add a new row at the top and bottom to close the ends:

```
[R, C] = size(Z);
Xfill = [X(1, 1:C) nan(1, C+1); ...  % Close top
         X flip(X, 2) X(:, 1); ...   % Flip data and connect to other side
         X(R, 1:C) nan(1, C+1)];     % Close bottom
Yfill = [Y(1, 1:C) nan(1, C+1); ...
         Y flip(Y, 2) Y(:, 1); ...
         Y(R, 1:C) nan(1, C+1)];
Zfill = [zeros(1, C) nan(1, C+1); ...
         Z zeros(R, C) Z(:, 1); ...
         zeros(1, C) nan(1, C+1)];

surf(Xfill, Yfill, Zfill);
view(-120, -20);
```

Again, you can plot the entire closed surface with a single call to `surf`. Here's the view from the underside, showing the closed bottom:

[image]

### Option #3: Add a separate surface object for the sides:

When plotting everything as one object, you're limited if you want to render the sides differently than the top. Making the sides separate objects like [Ander does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56362604/52738) (using [`patch`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) or a separate call to `surf`) will give you more control over how they are colored relative to the top surface. To make a single surface object for all four of your sides, you can extract the entries around the edges of your matrices and replicate them as needed:

```
[R, C] = size(Z);
Xside = [1; 1]*[X(1, :) ...           % Get first row
                X(2:R, C).' ...       % Get last column, without first row
                X(R, (C-1):-1:1) ...  % Get last row, without last column, flipped
                X((R-1):-1:1, 1).'];  % Get first column, without last row, flipped
Yside = [1; 1]*[Y(1, :) ...
                Y(2:R, C).' ....
                Y(R, (C-1):-1:1) ...
                Y((R-1):-1:1, 1).'];
Zside = [Z(1, :) ...
         Z(2:R, C).' ...
         Z(R, (C-1):-1:1) ...
         Z((R-1):-1:1, 1).'; ...
         zeros(1, 2*(R+C)-3)];

surf(X, Y, Z);  % Plot top surface
hold on;
surf(Xside, Yside, Zside, ...  % Plot all four sides...
     'EdgeColor', 'none', ...  %   with no edge coloring (i.e. grid)...
     'FaceAlpha', 0.5);        %   and transparency
view(-120, 30);
```

And the resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: easier than mine :D I did the other one because it was not clear to me if it was exactly what OP wanted, but if it is, this is the way

Comment: Thanks for the great help. This is closet to what I am looking for. @AnderBiguri Sorry for unclear description.

Comment: @hkshks: Happy to help! Just checking... did you mean to mark mine or Hoki's answer as accepted?

Comment: @gnovice Sorry my bad. I am new to this community. I have marked your answer as accepted. Anyway, I couldn't understand this part of the codes.


Xside = [1; 1]*[X(1, :) X(2:R, C).' ...
                X(R, (C-1):-1:1) X((R-1):-1:1, 1).'];
Yside = [1; 1]*[Y(1, :) Y(2:R, C).' ....
                Y(R, (C-1):-1:1) Y((R-1):-1:1, 1).'];
Zside = [Z(1, :) Z(2:R, C).' Z(R, (C-1):-1:1) Z((R-1):-1:1, 1).'; ...
         zeros(1, 2*(R+C)-3)];

Comment: @hkshks: I added a couple comments to that part to make it a little clearer. Basically, you're just tracing around the perimeter of the matrices and collecting the edge values. The `[1; 1]*[...]` part just uses matrix multiplication to replicate the row vector of edge values, and is equivalent to `repmat([...], 2, 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

The only way I can think is by looping over the edges, and filling them accordingly.

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);

Z = X.* sqrt(Y);

figure;


p=parula; % please do not use jet :(

surf(X,Y,Z) 
hold on;

%XZ init
for ii=1:size(Z,2)-1
    patch([X(1,ii) X(1,ii+1)  X(1,ii+1) X(1,ii)],...
          [Y(1,1) Y(1,1) Y(1,1) Y(1,1)],...
          [0  0 Z(1,ii+1) Z(1,ii) ],[p(1,:)]);
end

%XZ end
for ii=1:size(Z,2)-1
    patch([X(end,ii) X(end,ii+1)  X(end,ii+1) X(end,ii)],...
          [Y(end,1) Y(end,1) Y(end,1) Y(end,1)],...
          [0  0 Z(end,ii+1) Z(end,ii) ],[p(1,:)]);
end

%YZ init
for ii=1:size(Z,1)-1
    patch([X(1,1) X(1,1) X(1,1) X(1,1)],...
          [Y(ii,1) Y(ii+1,1) Y(ii+1,1) Y(ii,1)],...
          [0  0 Z(ii+1,1) Z(ii,1) ],[p(1,:)]);
end

%YZ end
for ii=1:size(Z,1)-1
    patch([X(1,end) X(1,end) X(1,end) X(1,end)],...
          [Y(ii,end) Y(ii+1,end) Y(ii+1,end) Y(ii,end)],...
          [0  0 Z(ii+1,end) Z(ii,end) ],[p(1,:)]);
end
colorbar

xlabel('Distance between two spatial points \xi_i & \xi_j (\xi_i - \xi_j)');

ylabel('Density(\rho)');

zlabel('Transmission Delay (t_t)');
```

There are a lot of style choices you can make now, like removing edges or changing the colors that I will leave to you as they can be found online.

If this is not exactly what you wanted, its still pretty much the way to do it. Using `patch` and appropriate coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way of using `patch` objects.

This solution is very similar to Ander's, but the `patch` construction is handled differently, so you don't need to loop and end up with only 4 patch entities to handle.

```
%% Prepare domain limits
xLim = [1 10] ; xStep = 0.5 ;
yLim = [1 20] ; yStep = 1 ;

x = xLim(1):xStep:xLim(2) ;
y = yLim(1):yStep:yLim(2) ;

%% Your code
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = X.* sqrt(Y);
figure;
surf(X,Y,Z) 
colorbar
xlabel('Distance between two spatial points \xi_i & \xi_j (\xi_i - \xi_j)');
ylabel('Density(\rho)');
zlabel('Transmission Delay (t_t)');

%% prepare patch elements
zLim = [min(Z) max(Z)] ;
pcol = [0.2857,1,0.7143] ;

xface = [ x xLim(2) xLim(1) ] ;
yface = [ y yLim(2) yLim(1) ] ;
xface0 = zeros(size(xface)) ;
yface0 = zeros(size(yface)) ;
xfaceZ = [zeros(size(x)) zLim(1) zLim(1)] ;
yfaceZ = [zeros(size(y)) zLim(1) zLim(1)] ;

%% display the patches
hp(1) = patch( xface , xface0+yLim(1) , xfaceZ ,pcol ) ;
hp(3) = patch( xface , xface0+yLim(2) , xfaceZ ,pcol ) ;
hp(2) = patch( yface0+xLim(1) , yface , yfaceZ ,pcol ) ;
hp(4) = patch( yface0+xLim(2) , yface , yfaceZ ,pcol ) ;

%% update top edge of patches
% to connect to the surface edges
hp(1).ZData(1:end-2) = Z(1,:) ;
hp(2).ZData(1:end-2) = Z(:,1) ;
hp(3).ZData(1:end-2) = Z(end,:) ;
hp(4).ZData(1:end-2) = Z(:,end) ;

%% Color according to preferences
set(hp, 'Facecolor',pcol , 'FaceAlpha',0.5 , 'EdgeColor','none')
```

Will render:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 0):

all these codes are not below the 3D surface. If you change the angle to see below the 3D graph, all area is empty. Only, edges are filled. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU8Aa.png)